# Converting call back to async/await functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to concert a callback function to stand chained functions, but could not manage it,

the callback function is:

```
db.transaction(
 function(t){
  t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM cal_list where calories > ?" ,[min_cal_amount], function(t,r){
     for (var i=0; i < r.rows.length; i++){
      food = r.rows.item(i).food;
      amount_of_calories = r.rows.item(i).amount_of_calories;
      serving_size = r.rows.item(i).serving_size;           
        
      list.innerHTML +="<li>"+food+" has "+amount_of_calories+" KCAL worth of calories.</li>";
                    
        }
    }, 
            
    function(t,e){alert(e.message);})
}
);
```

How can I convert to to `async..await` or `try..then..catch`?

Comment: You can use async-await with promise only. Is the function returning promise?

Comment: Which library are you using ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee `WebSQL` api

Answer (score 0):

If your database library exposes `db.transaction` and `t.executeSQL` in a promise based api, it would look roughly like this:

```js
async function getResults() {

    const transaction = await db.transaction();

    try {
        const result = await transaction.executSql(
            'SELECT * FROM cal_list where calories > ?',
            [min_cal_amount]
        );

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            // work with result data
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        // rollback transaction, handle error as appropriate
    }
}
```

If your library does not expose those functions in a promise based api, you can use `util.promisify` to wrap those functions that expect a callback, and then use the above snippet.

Comment: It looks it does not support `await`, I got: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: Once I tried `const transaction = db.transaction();` without `await` I got: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'Database': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.`

Comment: @HasanAYousef You either need to use a newer version of node that supports top level await, or wrap the entire thing in an async function.   I've updated the example